# Odoo 10 - function with CRON

Tags: python, cron, odoo

Here my function :

```
# Méthode CRON pour fermetures contrats
@api.model
def run_close_old_contracts(self):
    _logger.info('CRON Called for to verify closed dates contracts')
    domain = ['|', ('half_pension_unsubscribe_date', '<=', fields.Date.today()),
              ('nursery_morning_unsubscribe_date', '<=', fields.Date.today()),
              ('nursery_evening_unsubscribe_date', '<=', fields.Date.today())]
    for contract in self.search(domain):
        if contract.half_pension_unsubscribe_date <= fields.Date.today():
            if contract.half_pension_status == "3":
                contract.half_pension_status = "3"
        if contract.nursery_morning_unsubscribe_date <= fields.Date.today():
            if contract.nursery_status_morning == "3":
                contract.nursery_status_morning = "3"
        if contract.nursery_evening_unsubscribe_date <= fields.Date.today():
            if contract.nursery_status_evening == "3":
                contract.nursery_status_evening = "3"
```

So I use a CRON (automated action) to call this function.

The problem is that this function calls the write () method for each filled condition and all that for each record found.

I would like to call the write () method once and not every time I enter the condition.

I was thinking about the dictionary but I do not see how used it here.

Do you have an idea ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Just fill a dictionary and `write` at the end:

```py
@api.model
def run_close_old_contracts(self):
    _logger.info('CRON Called for to verify closed dates contracts')
    domain = ['|', ('half_pension_unsubscribe_date', '<=', fields.Date.today()),
            ('nursery_morning_unsubscribe_date', '<=', fields.Date.today()),
            ('nursery_evening_unsubscribe_date', '<=', fields.Date.today())]
    for contract in self.search(domain):
        to_write = {}
        if contract.half_pension_unsubscribe_date <= fields.Date.today():
            if contract.half_pension_status != "3":
                to_write['half_pension_status'] = "3"
        if contract.nursery_morning_unsubscribe_date <= fields.Date.today():
            if contract.nursery_status_morning != "3":
                to_write['nursery_status_morning'] = "3"
        if contract.nursery_evening_unsubscribe_date <= fields.Date.today():
            if contract.nursery_status_evening != "3":
                to_write['nursery_status_evening'] = "3"
        contract.write(to_write)
```

You compared every status with "equals 3" and also write "3" in the end. That doesn't make sense, so i changed "equals" to "doesn't equal" in the code above.

Edit: Hint from [Odoo's documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html#field-access)

> DANGER each assignment to a field triggers a database update, when
>   setting multiple fields at the same time or setting fields on multiple
>   records (to the same value), use write().